# using multiple instances of popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using a popup that perfectly suits my needs! what i want to do is add another instance of the same popup but its not working,basically i have two different popup i want to show depending on the scenario like one for register and one for login. the first instance named **somedialog** works fine but the instance **somedialog2** doesn't work here's my code

```
<a data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger icon icon-register">Register</a>
<a data-dialog="somedialog2" class="trigger icon icon-login">Login</a>

<div id="somedialog" class="dialog dialog--close">
    <div class="dialog__overlay"></div>
    <div class="dialog__content">
        <div class="morph-shape">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 560 280" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <rect x="3" y="3" fill="none" width="556" height="276"></rect>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="dialog-inner">
            <h2><strong>Wait!</strong>, Are you a teacher or a student?</h2>
            <div>
                <button style="display: none" class="action" data-dialog-close="a">Close</button>
                <button class="action" onclick="window.location.href='<?=base_url()?>Home/student_register'">I'm A Student</button>
                <button class="action" onclick="window.location.href='<?=base_url()?>Home/teacher_register'">I'm A Teacher</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="somedialog2" class="dialog dialog--close">
    <h1>here</h1>
    <div class="dialog__overlay"></div>
    <div class="dialog__content">
        <div class="morph-shape">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 560 280" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <rect x="3" y="3" fill="none" width="556" height="276"></rect>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="dialog-inner">
            <h2><strong>Wait!</strong>, Are you a teacher or a student?</h2>
            <div>
                <button style="display: none" class="action" data-dialog-close="a">Close</button>
                <button class="action" onclick="window.location.href='<?=base_url()?>Student'">I'm A Student</button>
                <button class="action" onclick="window.location.href='<?=base_url()?>Teacher'">I'm A Teacher</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
 ( function( window ) {

        'use strict';

        var support = { animations : Modernizr.cssanimations },
            animEndEventNames = { 'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd', 'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd', 'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd', 'animation' : 'animationend' },
            animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ],
            onEndAnimation = function( el, callback ) {
                var onEndCallbackFn = function( ev ) {
                    if( support.animations ) {
                        if( ev.target != this ) return;
                        this.removeEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndCallbackFn );
                    }
                    if( callback && typeof callback === 'function' ) { callback.call(); }
                };
                if( support.animations ) {
                    el.addEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndCallbackFn );
                }
                else {
                    onEndCallbackFn();
                }
            };

        function extend( a, b ) {
            for( var key in b ) {
                if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                    a[key] = b[key];
                }
            }
            return a;
        }

        function DialogFx( el, options ) {
            this.el = el;
            this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
            extend( this.options, options );
            this.ctrlClose = this.el.querySelector( '[data-dialog-close]' );
            this.isOpen = false;
            this._initEvents();
        }

        DialogFx.prototype.options = {
            // callbacks
            onOpenDialog : function() { return false; },
            onCloseDialog : function() { return false; }
        }

        DialogFx.prototype._initEvents = function() {
            var self = this;

            // close action
            this.ctrlClose.addEventListener( 'click', this.toggle.bind(this) );

            // esc key closes dialog
            document.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( ev ) {
                var keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
                if( keyCode === 27 && self.isOpen ) {
                    self.toggle();
                }
            } );

            this.el.querySelector( '.dialog__overlay' ).addEventListener( 'click', this.toggle.bind(this) );
        }

        DialogFx.prototype.toggle = function() {
            var self = this;
            if( this.isOpen ) {
                classie.remove( this.el, 'dialog--open' );
                classie.add( self.el, 'dialog--close' );

                onEndAnimation( this.el.querySelector( '.dialog__content' ), function() {
                    classie.remove( self.el, 'dialog--close' );
                } );

                // callback on close
                this.options.onCloseDialog( this );
            }
            else {
                classie.add( this.el, 'dialog--open' );

                // callback on open
                this.options.onOpenDialog( this );
            }
            this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
        };

        // add to global namespace
        window.DialogFx = DialogFx;

    })( window );


        (function() {
            var dlgtrigger = document.querySelector( '[data-dialog]' );
            console.log(dlgtrigger);
            var dlgtrigger = document.querySelector( '[data-dialog]' ),
                somedialog = document.getElementById( dlgtrigger.getAttribute( 'data-dialog' ) ),
                dlg = new DialogFx( somedialog );

            dlgtrigger.addEventListener( 'click', dlg.toggle.bind(dlg) );

        })();

        (function() {
            var dlgtrigger = document.querySelector( '[data-dialog]' );
            console.log(dlgtrigger);
            var dlgtrigger = '<a class="trigger icon icon-register" data-dialog="somedialog">',
                somedialog = "somedialog2",
                dlg = new DialogFx( somedialog );

            dlgtrigger.addEventListener( 'click', dlg.toggle.bind(dlg) );

        })();
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ashwinsaxena/pen/PwVaJO)

Comment: What does `DialogFx` function do?

Comment: @JoseRojas i have updated the code have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it,, the problem that you had was that your code only targeted one element id,, I only expanded it to account for all elements that have `[data-dialog]` property..

```js
/**
 * dialog box v0.1
 * Ashwin Saxena
 */
;
(function(window) {

  'use strict';

  var support = {
      animations: Modernizr.cssanimations
    },
    animEndEventNames = {
      'WebkitAnimation': 'webkitAnimationEnd',
      'OAnimation': 'oAnimationEnd',
      'msAnimation': 'MSAnimationEnd',
      'animation': 'animationend'
    },
    animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[Modernizr.prefixed('animation')],
    onEndAnimation = function(el, callback) {
      var onEndCallbackFn = function(ev) {
        if (support.animations) {
          if (ev.target != this) return;
          this.removeEventListener(animEndEventName, onEndCallbackFn);
        }
        if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
          callback.call();
        }
      };
      if (support.animations) {
        el.addEventListener(animEndEventName, onEndCallbackFn);
      } else {
        onEndCallbackFn();
      }
    };

  function extend(a, b) {
    for (var key in b) {
      if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        a[key] = b[key];
      }
    }
    return a;
  }

  function DialogFx(el, options) {
    this.el = el;
    this.options = extend({}, this.options);
    extend(this.options, options);
    this.ctrlClose = this.el.querySelector('[data-dialog-close]');
    this.isOpen = false;
    this._initEvents();
  }

  DialogFx.prototype.options = {
    // callbacks
    onOpenDialog: function() {
      return false;
    },
    onCloseDialog: function() {
      return false;
    }
  }

  DialogFx.prototype._initEvents = function() {
    var self = this;

    // close action
    this.ctrlClose.addEventListener('click', this.toggle.bind(this));

    // esc key closes dialog
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
      var keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
      if (keyCode === 27 && self.isOpen) {
        self.toggle();
      }
    });

    this.el.querySelector('.dialog__overlay').addEventListener('click', this.toggle.bind(this));
  }

  DialogFx.prototype.toggle = function() {
    var self = this;
    if (this.isOpen) {
      classie.remove(this.el, 'dialog--open');
      classie.add(self.el, 'dialog--close');

      onEndAnimation(this.el.querySelector('.dialog__content'), function() {
        classie.remove(self.el, 'dialog--close');
      });

      // callback on close
      this.options.onCloseDialog(this);
    } else {
      classie.add(this.el, 'dialog--open');

      // callback on open
      this.options.onOpenDialog(this);
    }
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  };

  // add to global namespace
  window.DialogFx = DialogFx;

})(window);

/* call */


(function() {

  var dlgs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dialog]');
  for( var i = 0; i < dlgs.length; i++){
    var dlgID = document.getElementById(dlgs[i].getAttribute('data-dialog'));
    var dlg = new DialogFx( dlgID );
    dlgs[i].addEventListener('click', dlg.toggle.bind(dlg));
  }

})();
```

```css
button {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #c94e50;
}

.dialog,
.dialog__overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.dialog {
  position: fixed;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.dialog__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(55, 58, 71, 0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.dialog--open .dialog__overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.dialog__content {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 560px;
  min-width: 290px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 0;
}

.dialog--open .dialog__content {
  pointer-events: auto;
}


/* Content */

.dialog h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0 0 2em;
  margin: 0;
}

.dialog--open .dialog__overlay {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.dialog--close .dialog__overlay {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.dialog__content {
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.dialog.dialog--open .dialog__content {
  opacity: 1;
}

.morph-shape {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
  height: calc(100% + 4px);
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.morph-shape svg rect {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 1680;
}

.dialog--open .morph-shape svg rect {
  -webkit-animation: anim-dash 0.6s forwards;
  animation: anim-dash 0.6s forwards;
}

.dialog-inner {
  opacity: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.dialog--open .dialog-inner {
  padding: 4em;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.85s 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.85s 0.35s;
}

.dialog.dialog--open h2 {
  -webkit-animation: anim-elem-1 0.7s ease-out both;
  animation: anim-elem-1 0.7s ease-out both;
}

.dialog.dialog--open button {
  -webkit-animation: anim-elem-2 0.7s ease-out both;
  animation: anim-elem-2 0.7s ease-out both;
}

@keyframes anim-dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1680;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1680;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}


/* Inner elements animations */

@-webkit-keyframes anim-elem-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-150px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes anim-elem-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-150px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-150px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-elem-2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(150px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes anim-elem-2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(150px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(150px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/DialogEffects/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/DialogEffects/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

<div class="button-wrap">
  <button data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger">Open Dialog 1</button>
</div>
<div class="button-wrap">
  <button data-dialog="somedialog1" class="trigger">Open Dialog 2</button>
</div>



<div id="somedialog" class="dialog dialog--close">
  <div class="dialog__overlay"></div>
  <div class="dialog__content">
    <div class="morph-shape">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 560 280" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect x="3" y="3" fill="none" width="556" height="276"></rect>
       </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="dialog-inner">
      <h2><strong>Howdy</strong>, I'm a dialog box 1</h2>
      <div><button class="action" data-dialog-close="a">Close</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="somedialog1" class="dialog dialog--close">
  <div class="dialog__overlay"></div>
  <div class="dialog__content">
    <div class="morph-shape">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 560 280" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect x="3" y="3" fill="none" width="556" height="276"></rect>
       </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="dialog-inner">
      <h2><strong>Howdy</strong>, I'm a dialog box 2</h2>
      <div><button class="action" data-dialog-close="a">Close</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```